# How to only show desktop version on mobile - Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

I want to show only the desktop version of my blogger site forever... The whole desktop version/design will be shown.

Visit my site and request the Desktop Version if you are on mobile, and thats exactly want I want to show on!
www.peleis.ml

This code is not working, its only change the m=1 to m=0 but not the design or view

```
<code>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
var curl = window.location.href;if (curl.indexOf('m=1') != -1) {curl = curl.replace('m=1', 'm=0');window.location.href = curl;}
//]]></script>
</code>
```

Comment: https://techubber.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-force-blogger-to-show-desktop.html <-IDK much about blogger but that looks helpful hopefully

Comment: Still the vertical mobile view is showing!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to force a desktop rendering by overriding the viewport width. Try adding this meta tag to your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />
```

However, depending on your site's layout, that may negatively impact desktop viewing.

Answer (score 1):

[image: screenshot]

Check if it is adding `"?m=1"` at the end of the URL it must be `"?m=0"`.

**SOURCE:** [How to Redirect Mobile Version to Non-Mobile in Blogger](https://www.bloggertipandtrick.net/redirect-mobile-to-non-mobile-in-blogger/)

Comment: Yah its change from m=1 to m=0 but the layout is not changing. Only the m=0 was change but not the layout/view

Answer (score 0):

From your blog dashboard, Go to **Theme** > click on gear icon > select **No. Show desktop theme on mobile devices.**

[image]

Comment: Its not working, its still showing the Mobile Layout. What I mean is the whole dekstop layout. Like the sidebar is on the right. But this option is not, the sidebar is still at the bottom.

Comment: OK, your site is mobile responsive and you can't do that without redesign your site layout.